# lint.xml file can not be found when i move it from module directory to project directory

Tags: android, gradle, android-lint

I have an lint.xml file and want to apply it to whole project but not only one module. 
It can't be found when i move it from module dir to project dir.

This is my config about lintOptions in build.gradle from `module`

```
  lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
        lintConfig file("../lint.xml")
    }
```

and my lint.xml file is under project dir.(same dir as settings.gradle)

Comment: It's a wild guess, but maybe write a function for retreiving the file?

Comment: However it is weird, file() function should exactly that. Maybe you have to copy it to module directory anyway?

Comment: @PanWrona Yes, i have no idea why, if i copy it to module directory, which means 
i need to change every copy when that lint file changed

Comment: hey I added a simple function (not sure if it works, but idea is here). Basically you can change one lint file and every time it should be put in every module you have this piece of code. You can also look if you can make it as a hmm global/util function so you only change it in one place

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it's not working exactly, but maybe you have to copy it to module directory anyway?

```
def copyLintFile(path) {
    from file(path)
    into file("lint.xml")
    file("lint.xml")
}

lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
        lintConfig copyLintFile("../lint.xml")
    }
```